# How to Remove Empty list Elements from nested List

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I remove Empty item such as Item A2[]

```
List = {[
    item[{ 
        A :"A",
            A1:"C",
                A2:[]
    item B[{
        B1: []
          }]
        ]}
      }]
```

Comment: I’m on mobile and your formatting could be better, however, this doesn’t look like a valid array or object..?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `delete` statement, it would go something like this:

```
if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined) {
      delete obj[propName];
}
```

You can use that inside a `for` loop if you have an array of items.

This is an abstract way to delete `keys` with `null` or `undefined` `values` from an object since your code isn't really that much clear.

**UPDATE:**

To implement similar functionality in `C#`, you will have to use the `.RemoveKey("Key")` function.

So for example say you have the `key` as `label` inside an `item object`, use the following syntax:

`item.RemoveKey("label");` or if it was in an `array` use: `item[index].RemoveKey("label");`

Hope this helped.

Comment: thank you for explanation. This work for JavaScript but if I want to do this in C# how can I do ? please guide me

Comment: @Jalal - I updated my answer to consider C#.